# How to get getClientOriginalName() from Image of array on Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I Have An Array from request Like This.... I have order_details table, and i want to update column category, remark and foto data where have orderid and skuid that i get from request,...

```
array:7 [▼
  "orderid" => "191121120129KUR"
  "_token" => "1ov7aCP8JzzokWNfMpwntTH0Dv084HqwIqMUfLd1"
  "orderdet" => array:5 [▼
    0 => array:4 [▼
      "skuid" => "10006"
      "category" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "1"
        1 => "2"
      ]
      "remark" => "remarks 1"
      "foto" => array:2 [▼ 
        0 => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#348 ▶}
        1 => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#349 ▶}
      ]
    ]
    1 => array:4 [▼
      "skuid" => "10007"
      "category" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "1"
      ]
      "remark" => "remarks 2"
      "foto" => array:4 [▼
        0 => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#350 ▶}
        1 => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#351 ▶}
        2 => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#352 ▶}
        3 => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#353 ▶}
      ]
    ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
      "skuid" => "10008"
      "remark" => null
    ]
    3 => array:2 [▼
      "skuid" => "10138"
      "remark" => null
    ]
    4 => array:2 [▼
      "skuid" => "10078"
      "remark" => null
    ]
  ]
  "actioncomplaint" => "1"
  "salahsiapa" => "3"
  "remarkcust" => null
  "remarkfresh" => "Dani"
]
```

I want to store name of image using getClientOriginalName(),...
How to get that name of images , this is my controller

```
foreach($request->orderdet as  $row)
        {
            $data = OrderDetail::where('data_order_id', $request->orderid)->where('skuid', $row['skuid'])->first();
            if(isset($row['category'])) {

                $data->remarkscomplaint = $row['remark'];
                $data->categorycomplaint = implode(',',  $row['category']);
                $data->fotocomplaint = $row['foto'];
                $data->save();
            }
        }
```

Comment: you can only use `getClientOriginalName()` when submitting a file using a html form. once you save the file then later you cant get the original file name. try saving the file name when storing in the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$fotos = $request->only(['foto']);
$fotoNames = []
foreach($fotos as $foto) {
 $fotoNames[] = $foto->getClientOriginalName();
}

$implodedFotos = implode(',' $fotoNames);
```

then

```
  foreach($request->orderdet as  $row) {
        $data = OrderDetail::where('data_order_id', $request->orderid)->where('skuid', $row['skuid'])->first();

        if(isset($row['category'])) {

          dd($row['foto']); //Array of Image

          $data->remarkscomplaint = $row['remark'];
          $data->categorycomplaint = implode(',',  $row['category']);
          $data->fotocomplaint = $implodedFotos; // <- set your attribute with the variable we create with the names
          $data->save();
        }
  }
```

I guess you could also do something like

```
$fotos = collect($request->orderset['foto'])
    ->map(function ($foto) {
    return $foto->getClientOriginalName();
    })
    ->implode(',');

$fotos->all(); // access the result
```

and then in order to save your images [this](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests#storing-uploaded-files) will help you.

```
$foto->storeAs('path', 'filename');
```

Comment: foreach($fotos as $foto) {
                    $fotoNames[] = $foto->getClientOriginalName();
                    // $foto->move(public_path().'/images/complaint/', $fotoNames);
                  
                }
For saved ? file image ? sir